# Javascript not rendering inline in HTML with Rich Text Publisher

Tags: javascript, html, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to print the below HTML code with embedded Javascript on the Jenkins (2.241) project page using the Rich Text Publisher plugin but the Javascript table loads at the very bottom of the page instead of on the right-hand side below the 'Recent Changes' link and above the "Hello World" where I need it. How can I fix this?

```html
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body,
        tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '500px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('ABC'));
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate();
</script>

<p style="font-size:40px">
Hello World.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You append it at the end of the `body` like `..<table/></body>` which is not the desired place most like. Either append it where it belongs or style it differently.

Comment: It matters less in this case where the script is placed yet more when it gets executed and where the rest of the DOM comes from and when. If your "Recent Changes" has an `id` or any means to get identified you can change this part `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'))` fitting `document.getElementById('xxx').appendChild(document.createElement('table'))`. If you want it always at the start of the body you can use `insertBefore(tbl, body.firstChild)` instead of `body.appendChild(tbl)`.

Comment: Brilliant! I was able to get the id of that element ('main-panel') and replaced the line `body.appendChild(tbl)` with `document.getElementById('main-panel').appendChild(tbl)` to get the table right below 'Recent Changes'. Thank you!